# Medias upload not working on Linkedin APIs

Tags: linkedin-api

We use the Linkedin's APIs on our platform to manage post-publishing and since some days ago we are having problems with some posts with photos and video that are not being published through the APIs.

I did some discoveries and finally found the problem. It's related to the medias status, that isn't changing from "Processing" to "Available", and due to that, the post isn't successfully published.

I need help to understand why this behavior is happening. Our platform is basically stopped due to this issue, so it's a high priority to us. Here are some details:

On 2023-05-18 23:58:25 (UTC) we started the upload for one image:
Image ID: urn:li:image:D4D10AQH06LymIb7cmQ
Result: {"owner":"urn:li:person:aKjCNdRm9b","status":"WAITING_UPLOAD","id":"urn:li:image:D4D10AQH06LymIb7cmQ"}

On 2023-05-18 23:58:29 (UTC) we checked the status of this image:
Image ID: urn:li:image:D4D10AQH06LymIb7cmQ
Result: {"owner":"urn:li:person:aKjCNdRm9b","status":"PROCESSING","id":"urn:li:image:D4D10AQH06LymIb7cmQ"}

On 2023-05-19 14:08:12 (UTC) we checked the status of this image:
Image ID: urn:li:image:D4D10AQH06LymIb7cmQ
Result:
{"downloadUrl":"https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/D4D10AQH06LymIb7cmQ/image-shrink_1280/0/1684454309568?e=1685113200&v=beta&t=PUoY60j5y0jgeRWIzySfn5xm-0B_CRjT5Qhuwo0sIDg","owner":"urn:li:person:aKjCNdRm9b","id":"urn:li:image:D4D10AQH06LymIb7cmQ","downloadUrlExpiresAt":1685113200000,"status":"PROCESSING"}

Can you please help me to understand why this is getting stuck at this status?

Thanks in advance.

We tried several time to upload, some times the API run succesfully and the post is published, but sometimes it doesn't happen.